# Javascript variable scope question

Tags: javascript, json

I am confused with the variable scope in Javascript. I am trying to load data file (.json) using Prototype library and parse the response text using json-sans-eval. The problem is it seems to me that the content from data file is lost if I tried to access "dataObj" outside of the Ajax.Request scope.

The variable in Javascript has reference count. I don't understand how can the global variable 'dataObj' will lose its data. Any hint or help?

Thank you!

```
var dataObj;
function OnLoadHandle() {
    new Ajax.Request('data.json',
    {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport)
        {
            var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
            dataObj = jsonParse(response);
            console.log(dataObj["[0,0]"]); // OK
        },
        onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
    });
    console.log(dataObj["[0,0]"]); // ERROR 
}
```

Comment: It's not about scope, the issues is that _A_jax is _A_synchronous, the second `console.log` is being executed *before* the request completes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second invocation of `console.log(...)` at the end of `OnLoadHandle` runs immediately, whereas the one inside `onSuccess` runs only after the request completes. The second `console.log` serves no purpose.

More broadly, this means that there is no point in making `dataObj` a global variable. It is only useful after it is assigned in `onSuccess` and should therefore be scoped as a local variable within `onSuccess`. If you need it elsewhere, `onSuccess` should pass it as a parameter to some other function.